# Scale and crop an image in python PIL without exceeding the image dimensions

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, crop, image-scaling

I am cropping an image using python PIL. Say my image is as such:

[image]

This is the simple code snippet I use for cropping:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(image)
cropped_image = im.crop((topLeft_x, topLeft_y, bottomRight_x, bottomRight_y))
cropped_image.save("Out.jpg")
```

The result of this is:

[image]

I want to scale out this cropped image keeping the aspect ratio (proportionate width and height) same by say 20% to look something like this without exceeding the image dimensions.

[image]

How should I scale out the crop such that the aspect ratio is maintained while not exceeding the image boundary/ dimensions?

Comment: You are not cropping and then scaling the cropped part actually. Really, you are taking a larger crop, aren't you?

Comment: Try working out the width and height of your crop, and the x,y centre. With the new crop, the centre will be the same but the width and height will each be 20% more, i.e. newwidth = 1.2 * oldwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should calculate the center of your crop and use it there on.
As an example:

```
crop_width = right - left
crop_height = bottom - top
crop_center_x = int(left + crop_width/2)
crop_center_y = (top + crop_height/2)
```

In this way you will obtain the (x,y) point which corresponds to the center of your crop w.r.t your original image.
In that case, you will know that the maximum width for your crop would be the **minimum** between the center value and the outer bounds of the original image minus the center itself:

```
im = Image.open("brad.jpg")
l = 200
t = 200
r = 300
b = 300
cropped = im.crop((l, t, r, b))
```

Which gives you:

[image]

If you want to "enlarge" it to the maximum starting from the same center, then you will have:

```
max_width = min(crop_center_x, im.size[0]-crop_center_x)
max_height = min(crop_center_y, im.size[1]-crop_center_y)
new_l = crop_center_x - max_width
new_t = crop_center_x - max_height
new_r = crop_center_x + max_width
new_b = crop_center_x + max_height
new_crop = im.crop((new_l, new_t, new_r, new_b))
```

which gives as a result, having the same center:

[image]

---

#### Edit

If you want to keep the aspect ratio you should retrieve it (the ratio) before and apply the crop only if the resulting size would still fit the original image. As an example, if you want to enlarge it by 20%:

```
ratio = crop_height/crop_width
scale = 20/100
new_width = int(crop_width + (crop_width*scale))

# Here we are using the previously calculated value for max_width to 
# determine if the new one would be too large.
# Note that the width that we calculated here (new_width) refers to both
# sides of the crop, while the max_width calculated previously refers to
# one side only; same for height. Sorry for the confusion.
if max_width < new_width/2:
    new_width = int(2*max_width)

new_height = int(new_width*ratio)

# Do the same for the height, update width if necessary
if max_height < new_height/2:
    new_height = int(2*max_height)
    new_width = int(new_height/ratio)

adjusted_scale = (new_width - crop_width)/crop_width

if adjusted_scale != scale:
    print("Scale adjusted to: {:.2f}".format(adjusted_scale))

new_l = int(crop_center_x - new_width/2)
new_r = int(crop_center_x + new_width/2)
new_t = int(crop_center_y - new_height/2)
new_b = int(crop_center_y + new_height/2)
```

Once you have the width and height values the process to get the crop is the same as above.

Comment: This is a nice approach but when it scales out it adds a black patch on the area that exceeds the image. You can see my implementation of your approach here (see the crop_face function): https://pastebin.com/FYfs20Ba and the cropped image here: https://ibb.co/8jwnrPP .

As you will see, the cropping and scaling has added a black patch on the top. How do we avoid that? One obvious approach is to reduce the scaling, but I want to do that intelligently. I want to reduce the scaling only if the cropped image scale exceeds the original image dimensions.

Comment: Of course, my bad. First of all, the check should be done on crop_center_x + new_width/2 (for height as well) and also the new_l and new_r needs to be updated with +- new_width/2. What's more, an other check should be done so that new_height/2 <= crop_center_y and new_width/2 <= crop_center_x in order to check that also on the left and top sides the crop size doesn't exceed the boundaries. I will update my answer with these corrections as I get my hands on the PC, would you try it in the meantime?

Comment: @FlyingAura I have updated the code, now it should work. Please, pay attention to the difference between __max_width__ and __new_width__ : the former refers to the maximum width __PER__ side, while the latter refers to the global new width for the crop

Comment: In `max_width = min(x, im.size[0]-x)`, What is `x` here, Is it same as `crop_center_x `? Also, where do we use `adjusted_scale `?

Comment: I have made changes in the code as per your answer but the result is still same: https://pastebin.com/WuEPQjbZ
What am I missing? Could you please post the code snippet?

Comment: @FlyingAura yes, the x is the same as the center_crop_x. What you are missing in your pastebin is the last part: you should have new_l = crop_center_x - new_width/2. It is the issue I was referring to in my previous comment and in the code as well. Same for the others: new_r, new_t, new_b need half the new_width and height to be added / subtracted. Also, we don't use adjusted_scale, it is there just for the sake of showing that it may have changed, in case you want to print it.
I have updated the answer with the final part and corrected the x and y to center_crop_x / y

Comment: In the future, can we use pictures that aren't so gosh darn distracting from the code implementation? Thanks